# Call a frameset reference in a 2nd html

Tags: html, css

I have a frameset, where the right frame have buttons which on click redirects to defined html pages.

Similarly i want to achieve the same simultaneously on click of the radio button 2 on the right frame, my corresponding image should be loaded on the left frame.

Have tried something like this:

```
<html>
<frameset cols="25%,75% scrolling=" no ">

    <frame name="left " src="help_q1_image.html " scrolling=no />
    <frame name="center " src="help_q1.html " scrolling=no />
</frameset>

</html>
```

AS of now only the image defined  in help_q1_image.html loads.

When i click on button/link 2, its corresponding image should load.

Comment: `<frameset>` and `<frame>` are deprecated therefore you should look for an alternative approach.

Comment: Show the html with the button/link 2  - a target of "center" from left will work as will a target of "left" from center

Comment: Could you give an example

Comment: I think you got a few things badly wrong. No offense. If you are looking to achieve something like this you need to set some principles. 

As @Waxi said, using <frameset> and <frame> is deprecated and judging by what you want to achieve, using this actually draws you back.

For starters, you should create a single HTML page and use javascript to toggle the loaded image. There are several libraries out there so it should not be scary.